# My app exit when I decompile and recompile the smali file called classes.Dex with apktool and backsmali tools

Tags: java, android, decompiler, smali, apktool

iam getting this error after i recompile **dex file**.
i used : **apktool d --no-src --no-res original.apk -o decompiled**
the application decompiled succesfully then i used : **java -jar baksmali-2.5.2.jar d classes.dex**
when decompiling the dex file i get some **warnings** :

```
Lcom/ano/gshell/AnoApplication;-><clinit>()V: Invalid debug offset
Lcom/ano/gshell/AnoApplication;-><init>()V: Invalid debug offset
Lcom/ano/gshell/AnoApplication;->dec(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;: Invalid debug offset
Lcom/ano/gshell/AnoApplication;->dec(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;: Invalid debug offset
Lcom/ano/gshell/AnoApplication;->attachBaseContext(Landroid/content/Context;)V: Invalid debug offset
Lcom/ano/gshell/AnoApplication;->attachBaseContext(Landroid/content/Context;)V: Invalid debug offset
```

but then i **change nothing** and recompile using : **java -jar smali-2.5.2.jar a out**

and **replace the new dex** with the orinial dex then i run apktool using : **apktool b decompiled -o example.apk**
then i **resign the apk** and install it.
the new apk **install successfully and lunching**
the **problem** is when i **get to lobby the app exit**.
this is the **logcat of the crash**:

```
0-16 20:43:30.742 22936 22936 W dex2oat : /system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg & --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2,-lock_add,-popcnt --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/user/0/com.dts.example/cache/app_resources_lib.jar --oat-fd=120 --oat-location=/data/user/0/com.dts.example/code_cache/app_resources_lib.dex --compiler-filter=speed
10-16 20:43:31.680 22936 22936 I dex2oat : /system/bin/dex2oat --dex-file=/data/user/0/com.dts.example/cache/app_resources_lib.jar --oat-fd=120 --oat-location=/data/user/0/com.dts.example/code_cache/app_resources_lib.dex --compiler-filter=speed
10-16 20:43:36.492 22998 22998 W dex2oat : /system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg & --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2,-lock_add,-popcnt --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/user/0/com.dts.example/cache/google_api_resources_lib.jar --oat-fd=73 --oat-location=/data/user/0/com.dts.example/code_cache/google_api_resources_lib.dex --compiler-filter=speed
10-16 20:43:36.492 22998 22998 I dex2oat : /system/bin/dex2oat --dex-file=/data/user/0/com.dts.example/cache/google_api_resources_lib.jar --oat-fd=73 --oat-location=/data/user/0/com.dts.example/code_cache/google_api_resources_lib.dex --compiler-filter=speed
10-16 20:43:52.799 22540 23202 E cr_VariationsUtils: Failed reading seed file "/data/user/0/com.dts.example/app_webview/variations_seed_new": /data/user/0/com.dts.example/app_webview/variations_seed_new (No such file or directory)
10-16 20:43:52.804 22540 23202 E cr_VariationsUtils: Failed reading seed file "/data/user/0/com.dts.example/app_webview/variations_seed": /data/user/0/com.dts.example/app_webview/variations_seed (No such file or directory)
10-16 20:44:03.272 22540 22609 I YOUME : Φ░âτö¿init σç╜µò░ σ╝Çσºï∩╝îτ¢«σ╜ò:/data/user/0/com.dts.example/app_libs
10-16 20:44:04.473 22540 22609 D houdini : [22609] Added shared library /data/app/com.dts.example-1/lib/arm/libyoume_voice_engine.so for ClassLoader by Native Bridge.
10-16 20:44:07.246 22540 22609 I YOUME : package:com.dts.example
10-16 20:44:16.214 22540 22609 D houdini : [22609] Added shared library /data/app/com.dts.example-1/lib/arm/libGGP.so for ClassLoader by Native Bridge.
10-16 20:44:25.647 586 1120 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{91e48a9 u0 com.dts.example/com.dts.example.FFMainActivity}
10-16 20:44:25.648 586 1120 W WindowManager: Force-removing child win Window{3caeb7 u0 SurfaceView - com.dts.example/com.dts.example.FFMainActivity} from container Window{91e48a9 u0 com.dts.example/com.dts.example.FFMainActivity}
10-16 20:44:25.648 586 661 I ActivityManager: Process com.dts.example (pid 22540) has died
10-16 20:44:25.675 586 661 W ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{98405cd u0 com.dts.example/.FFMainActivity t187}: app died, no saved state
```

**note:**
the application runs without error when compile with **original classes.dex** .
but exit with the one that decompiled and **recompiled with backsmali**.

-and here is the **download link** for the app [Download](https://www.mediafire.com/file/inv3wrnzbmbs02n/original_app.apk/file)

Comment: I would check if the app works if you just resign it (without decompiling or recompiling). The crash log is pretty short which could mean that the app has terminated itself because it has detected the repackaging or some other modification.

Comment: the app did work if i just resign it. remember the app exit on lobby not in the beginning.